# Can I calculate the moment in different parts (in an assembly) in Blender?

Tags: modeling, physics

Can I calculate the moment in different parts in an assembly in Blender?

I would need to calculate the moment affecting a machine when lifting different weight of objects. Can this kind of calculations be done in Blender? I'm trying to find this out before starting to learn Blender

I can see there are nice simulations, but I would need the calculations in different positions.

Comment: short answer: AFAIK: no

Comment: I don't think so, each vertex is given a weight but I'm not sure how the weight is distributed